# sf.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: IO Error -> java.net.SocketException: Too many open files

Tags: java, linux, spring

A java program throws below exception when there is increased load. I am not sure why this exception
**Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files** is occurring.

dbpool.size=200

```
*org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:625)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:690)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:722)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:732)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:782)
        at com.dao.SomeAgentDAO.updateStatus(SomeAgentDAO.java:266)
        at com.processor.SomeAgent.updateConfigured(SomeAgent.java:1919)
        at com.SomeAgent.call(SomeAgent.java:489)
        at com.processor.SomeAgent.call(SomeAgent.java:100)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:774)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.connect(PhysicalConnection.java:702)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:39)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:691)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:55)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:355)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:899)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:429)
        at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:354)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:134)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:753)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:411)
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.socket(Net.java:404)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.<init>(SocketChannelImpl.java:105)
        at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openSocketChannel(SelectorProviderImpl.java:60)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:145)
        at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(SocketChannel.java:187)
        at oracle.net.nt.TimeoutSocketChannel.<init>(TimeoutSocketChannel.java:81)
        at oracle.net.nt.TcpNTAdapter.connect(TcpNTAdapter.java:169)
        ... 32 more*
```

Comment: Did you open multiple sockets without closing them?

Comment: You are leaking sockets or files: either JDBC connections (most likely), or sockets or files elsewhere in your application.

Comment: @user207421 JDBC connection should not make issue. I have checked the max active connection was 32. I am not using any socket connection or file handling in code.

Comment: @dan1st sockets are not being used.

Comment: Well something is the issue, isn't it? Are you using try-with-resources blocks everywhere you acquire a JDBC connection? or closing them in `finally` blocks?

Comment: You will never et an answer here until you provide some code and answer the questions you are asked.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the linux OS ulimit.
Increased the maxopenfile limit, Which solved my problem.